# The websocket connection for rails chat is not established

Tags: websocket, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to make a simple chat on RoR, I do this for this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJbuZecN1c8

at the stage of checking the connection websocket, the console displays the following error

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/cable' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

what can it be connected to? What are the possible solutions?

UPDATE:

rails logs raise error:

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04- 06 18:19:44 +0300
LoadError (/home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nio4r- 2.3.0/lib/nio4r_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb_cFixnum - /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nio4r-2.3.0/lib/nio4r_ext.so)
```

Comment: 500 = internal server error. Something's wrong in your setup and an exception should have been raised (and probably logged). **What do the RoR application logs say**?

Comment: rails logs raise error `Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-
06 18:19:44 +0300
  
LoadError (/home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nio4r-
2.3.0/lib/nio4r_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb_cFixnum - 
/home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nio4r-2.3.0/lib/nio4r_ext.so):`

Comment: @Myst thanks for the hint, it was just necessary `gem install nio4r -v '2.3.0'`

Comment: I'm happy you found a solution. You can post an answer to your own question. If future developers will find it useful, they will up vote the answer. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just necessary do `gem install nio4r -v '2.3.0'`